# Using input[date] directive with Angular 1.2 and 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to have an input of type 'date' in my page and I am thinking of using angularJs 'input[date]' directive.

But Angular 1.2 does not have it and my application should work with both Angular 1.2 and 1.3. I can write my own directive for date input, but what I want is if my code is used with Angular 1.3 angular's directive for 'input[date]' should be used and else my custom directive should be used.

How should I implement this.

Comment: Have you tried writing 2 directives? 1 checking ng version and deciding to use either the native input[date] or your custom one.

Comment: yep I also just thought of doing this, angular provides variable angular.version.minor which I can use to check version of angular.